# Material UI table data refresh after redux update data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am using material-ui data table to display the data and when the user clicks on any row, user can update the data and save it via form.
I have used react-redux to maintain the state and dispatch the updated row to existing data. I am getting back the updated data via redux to my component but material-ui table is not updating with the new data.
But when i refresh the page, the new data gets updated. Below are the code snippets:

```
const StaffTable = ({selected, allRows, dispatch}) => {
    console.log('allRows: ',allRows); // This statement gets executed whenever i dispatch updated data from another component
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState('asc');
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState('sort');
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
    const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(allRows);
..
..
 return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                <EnhancedTableToolbar handler={handleFilter}/>
                <TableContainer>
                    <Table
                        className={classes.table}
                        aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
                        size={'small'}
                        aria-label="enhanced table"
                    >
                        <EnhancedTableHead
                            classes={classes}
                            order={order}
                            orderBy={orderBy}
                            onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                            rowCount={rows.length}
                        />
                        <TableBody>
                            {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                .map((row, index) => {
                                    const isItemSelected = isSelected(row.ppsn);
                                    const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                                    return (
                                        <TableRow
                                            hover
                                            onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, row)}
                                            role="checkbox"
                                            aria-checked={isItemSelected}
                                            tabIndex={-1}
                                            key={row.ppsn}
                                            selected={isItemSelected}
                                        >

                                            <TableCell component="th" id={labelId} scope="row">
                                                {row.disp}
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{row.ppsn}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{row.dob}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell>{row.town}</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    );
                                })}

                        </TableBody>
                    </Table>
                </TableContainer>
                <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
                    component="div"
                    count={rows.length}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                />
            </Paper>
        </div>
    );
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => createStructuredSelector({
    selected: selectSelectedStaff,
    allRows: selectAllStaffList,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(StaffTable);
```

**Dispatching Component:**

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(selected)); //selected will have updated row of table
        dispatch(updateStaff(clone));
```

**Action.js**

```
export const selectAllStaff = () => ({
    type: AllStaffActionTypes.SELECT_ALL_STAFF
})

export const updateStaff = (staffToUpdate) => ({
    type: AllStaffActionTypes.UPDATE_STAFF,
    payload: staffToUpdate
})
    }
```

**Reducer:**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    list: ALL_STAFF //this will have initial set of data rows
}

const allStaffReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AllStaffActionTypes.SELECT_ALL_STAFF:
            return state;
        case AllStaffActionTypes.UPDATE_STAFF:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: updateStaff(state.list, action.payload),
            }; 
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default allStaffReducer;
```

**Util.js**

```
export const updateStaff = (staffItems, staffToUpdate) => {
    let found = false;
    const result = staffItems.map(staff => {
        if (staff.ppsn === staffToUpdate.ppsn) {
            found = true;
            return staffToUpdate;
        } else {
            return staff;
        }
    });
    if (!found) {
        result.push(staffToUpdate);
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Selector:**

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const selectAllStaff = state => state.allstaff;

export const selectAllStaffList = createSelector(
    [selectAllStaff],
```

(allstaff) => allstaff.list
)

**root-reducer.js:**

```
import staffReducer from './staff/staff.reducer';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['allstaff']
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    staff: staffReducer,
    allstaff: allStaffReducer,
})

export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
```

Comment: This operation: React.useState(allRows) is performed once, only when the StaffTable component is mounted (and after reboot).

Comment: @MaxAlex so there is no option other than refreshing the page? I’m quite new to react. Do you suggest anything?

Comment: Try adding the following after: React.useState(allRows); React.useEffect(() => { setRows(allRows) }, [allRows]);

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked. You saved my day. If you can you put this in answer section   I will mark it as solved?

Comment: Enjoy it, glad to have been helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation: `const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(allRows)` is performed once,
only when the StaffTable component is mounted (and after reboot).

In order to reflect changes to the allRows property, add the hook useEffect:

```
const StaffTable = ({selected, allRows, dispatch}) => {
    console.log('allRows: ',allRows); 
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState('asc');
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState('sort');
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
    const [rows, setRows] = React.useState(allRows);

    React.useEffect(() => { setRows(allRows) }, [allRows]);
```